# Phonegap database storage

Tags: mysql, sqlite, cordova

In the phonegap documentation it states:

> "This method will create a new SQL Lite Database"

this is the only hint at not using traditional SQL, but is SQL Lite different to sqlite?

The code I am wanting to run was using mySQL, I have tested it in sqlite and it will not work the same way so it'd be annoying if I have to go rewriting it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With PhoneGap, you always get SQLite, which *is* a traditional SQL engine.
(There are very few [differences](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) to the SQL standard.)

With MySQL, you have more [differences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/differences-from-ansi.html), and it is likely that you have used some of its non-traditional [extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/extensions-to-ansi.html).

If you do want to use your MySQL-specific code in PhoneGap, your only choice is to rewrite it.